# How to compute camera rotation without depth

Tags: computer-vision, homography

I have the camera's intrinsic parameters. 
I capture one RGB image, rotate the camera, and capture another one. I have no access to depth images.
How can i compute the rotation?

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25255049/finding-transformation-between-two-frames

Answer (score 1):

Minimal solution: you only need to match one point in both images. "Shoot" a ray in 3D through the matched pixel in each image, then solve for the rotation between the two rays. The rotation axis is parallel to the cross product of the two rays.

More robust solution: match >= 4 points, compute the homography between the images, then decompose it into the product of a rotation and a translation.