# Plane construction from 3D Points in OpenCV

Tags: opencv

I would like to construct a plane from a list of 3D points in OpenCV. I would like to obtain the result by finding the four parameters in the following form: `Ax+By+Cz+D = 0`. Would anyone suggest me a way to do it?

Comment: Does the data contain outliers?

Comment: principal component analysis should give good results in theory. I'd suggest you a simple RANSAC method though. You should present a 3D image of your points to give an idea about your setting.

Comment: Maybe some kind of linear least squares may help you?

Comment: @HumamHelfawi Well, at this point outliers are ignored

Comment: So see my answer it is going to solve the problem, you may ask about any ambiguity.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the data does not contain outliers and does not contain more than one plane. Furthermore, all the points lay exactly on a plane (the data is not noisy), it is so simple:

1. Pick up three random points which are not lay on the same line.
2. solve this system of linear equations:

> ```
> x1+by1+cz1+d = 0
> x2+by2+cz2+d = 0
> x3+by3+cz3+d = 0
> ```

then :

> ```
> A= Choose any number you want in order to match your scale. 
> B= b*A 
> C= c*A 
> D= d*A
> ```

If the data is noisy or contains outliers or more than plane (or both) you need then some kind of Robust Estimation techniques. Search for RANSAC as a start.

if you are familar with RANSAC you can see [this example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33629842/grouping-points-that-represent-lines/) here (it is about lines you can simply generlize it to deal with plane)

Comment: Finally, I find a way by using the class SVD to solve the problem.  
First I transform the equation of plane from 
`AX+BY+CZ+D = 0` to `A'X+B'Y+C' = Z`, so the required parameters to characterize a plane becomes 3.
Then by applying `SVD sample(leftMatrix); sample.backSubst(z, result);`
where leftMatrix is a n*3 matrix containing each row (x_i, y_i, 1), z is just all the points of z coordinates in n*1 matrix form, variable"result" finally conotains the calculated plane parameters.

Comment: Anyway, thank you for your answer as your answer inspried me to reach my current solution.

Comment: glad it helped. You may accept this answer or try to write a full answer by yourself and accept your own. good luck

Answer (score 1):

## Answer by leveraging OpenCV

If you want to have equation solved by 3 points, just like follows:

`ax + by + cz = 1`

### Example

you have three points: cv::Point3f p1, p2 and p3, and here is the code:

```
cv::Matx33f M(p1.x, p1.y, p1.z,
              p2.x, p2.y, p2.z,
              p3.x, p3.y, p3.z);
cv::Vec3f d(1, 1, 1);
cv::Vec3f coef = M.inv() * d;
```

Then, a, b, c are coef(0), coef(1), coef(2) sequentially.